How do I install language model for spacy on Kaggle?
Aloha! Everybody knows how to install model at home:

python -m spacy download ru_core_news_md

But since python notebook on Kaggle is isolated of the global web, it does not seem possible to do so.
Of course, I can download ru_core_news_sm-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl file from spacy.io website and upload it into my dataset "ru-core-news-sm" on Kaggle.
Question is, how do I import it in my Spacy? I will be very appreciative for any kind of answer!

As far as I know, it is possible to use magic commands in the Kaggle notebooks such as the !pip install but I can imagine that you can use the !python -m spacy command as well.

Does this answer your question? Cannot access internet on Kaggle Notebook Once internet is enabled you can run magic commands as @PéterSzilvási pointed out.
